# Why does animation in child component fail? (GSAP)

Tags: reactjs, gsap

Please find the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gsap-j6jv89?file=/src/App.js) for your reference.

In the example, I have GSAP in both parent and child component.
They work fine separately, but when I import and use the child component, the animation on child component fails. (The green box is suppose to pin)